# How to uglify code only for deployment in maven

Tags: maven, uglifyjs

I want to uglify my javascript code before deployment on aws. I do not want to uglify the code during development. Do I need two separate pom files or is there a smart way to tell maven about that? I am using the uglifyjs plugin for maven.

Ren

Comment: Using maven profiles is the way to go here

Comment: Basically, you create two profiles.  A default profile that uses activation by default where it's always running.  That profile would build normally, not invoking the plugin.  Then a second profile that would run that plugin but only when you invoke the profile.  Have the profile only active when you deploy to aws.

Comment: Yes stick with one pom and use profiles. The default profile is generally what you would use for production.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will look into it and post and answer once I got it working.

Comment: Useful documentation here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html

Comment: Why is everyone posting comments that are answers instead of simply answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to @Michael for answering this, I will still answer formally in order to close this thread.

Here is what my maven profiles look like, note the activation block at the top, this is here to specify how to use this profile over the default profile, in this case I need to give the extra argument:

> $ mvn  -Ddeployment

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
     <activation>
        <property>
           <name>deployment</name>
        </property>
     </activation>

     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
           <id>uglifyjs-maven-plugin</id>
           <url>https://raw.github.com/tqh/uglifyjs-maven-plugin/master/repo</url>
        </pluginRepository>
     </pluginRepositories>

     <build>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
              <groupId>net.tqh.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>uglifyjs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.0</version>
              <configuration>
                 <sourceDirectory>target/snapshot/javascript</sourceDirectory>
                 <outputDirectory>target/snapshot/javascript</outputDirectory>
              </configuration>
              <executions>
                 <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                       <goal>uglify</goal>
                    </goals>
                 </execution>
              </executions>
           </plugin>

           <plugin>
              ... other plugins here ...
           </plugin>
        </plugins>
     </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```